# HTTP connection to JIRA XRAY Rest API not working

Tags: java, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

Need help
I am trying to connect to XRAY JIRA using Rest API and want to execute a case but getting 400  error response  at step **inputStream=new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8")**

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:

My Code is below:

```
    *HttpURLConnection con=null;
    InputStreamReader inputStream=null;
        URL jira_API_URL=new URL("https://jira.abc.com/rest/raven/latest/import/execution");
        
        
          String encodeCredentials=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
          "kkris:testjira@234".getBytes("UTF-8"));
          con=(HttpURLConnection)jira_API_URL.openConnection();
          con.setRequestMethod("POST"); con.setDoOutput(true);
          con.setRequestProperty("Autherization", "Basic "+encodeCredentials);
          con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
          con.setRequestProperty("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
         
                 

        try(OutputStream os=con.getOutputStream()){
            byte[] input=json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            os.write(input,0,input.length);
        }
        inputStream=new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");*
```

**Note** :Would like to add that I am able to hit this RestAPI using postman and Restassured & able to execute testcase in XRAYJIRA successfully

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all we need to clarify if you have Xray on Jira server/datacenter or Xray on Jira cloud, as they are different products and the APIs are also slightly different.
From your example, it seems that you're targetting Xray on Jira server/datacenter, and that you aim to import results using the Xray JSON format and respective endpoint as detailed [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-XrayJSONresults).
The endpoint URL in that case should either be
<jira_base_url>/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution or <jira_base_url>/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution

Also, please make sure the Xray JSON content you submit follows [this syntax](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results#ImportExecutionResults-XrayJSONformat).

Note: you may want to have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets) which contains some sample code for submiting results in Java and other languages, including a [proof-of-concept client api](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/tree/main/use_cases/import_automation_results/java/xray-code-snippets/src/main/java/com/idera/xray).

The response body content may show you clues about what's wrong. You can start by using `curl` utility first as shown [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-XrayJSONresults) and then implement the java code.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -u admin:admin --data @data.json http://yourserver/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I was using wrong spelling of authorization so so corrected it . but I am getting 400 now. I want to add that I am able to hit JIRA XRAY API successfully using Postman and RestAssured too. Also, 1.0,latest both works fine when i tried using postpman .Need help in above code

Comment: Updated more details and deleted print command. Now error moves to input stream